# Cropping Image to Oval in HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've been trying to crop an image to an oval shape using the method of creating another canvas, clipping that, saving it and then drawing the image onto my main canvas. However, it only shows the black oval without the image overlayed on top

```
var Ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
var tCan = document.createElement('canvas');
var tCtx = tCan.getContext('2d');


tCtx.beginPath();
var centerX = 50;
var centerY = 50;
var width = 100;
var height = 100;

tCtx.moveTo(centerX, centerY - height/2);

tCtx.bezierCurveTo(
centerX + width/2, centerY - height/2,
centerX + width/2, centerY + height/2,
centerX, centerY + height/2);

tCtx.bezierCurveTo(
centerX - width/2, centerY + height/2,
centerX - width/2, centerY - height/2,
centerX, centerY - height/2);

tCtx.fillStyle = "black";
tCtx.fill();
tCtx.closePath();   

var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){
tCtx.drawImage(img,1,1, 98, 98);
};

img.src = 'http://imgur.com/GvRewu7.png';

tCtx.clip();

var cSi = tCan.toDataURL();

var cImg = new Image();
cImg.src = cSi;

Ctx.drawImage(cImg,0,0);
```

Why is this not including the image cropped as well? Is there another way I can do this (entirely in javascript)?

Edit: My active JSBin page for this: https://jsbin.com/yulituc/edit?js,output

Answer (score 3):

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/mdofqjx2/3/

You haven't appended your new `canvas` element to the page. I have fixed it for you below

HTML :

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400">
</canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2" width="400" height="400">
</canvas>
```

Javascript :

```
var Ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
var tCan = document.getElementById('canvas2');
var tCtx = tCan.getContext('2d');

tCtx.beginPath();
var centerX = 50;
var centerY = 50;
var width = 100;
var height = 100;

tCtx.moveTo(centerX, centerY - height/2);

tCtx.bezierCurveTo(
centerX + width/2, centerY - height/2,
centerX + width/2, centerY + height/2,
centerX, centerY + height/2);

tCtx.bezierCurveTo(
centerX - width/2, centerY + height/2,
centerX - width/2, centerY - height/2,
centerX, centerY - height/2);

tCtx.fillStyle = "black";
tCtx.fill();
tCtx.closePath();   

var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){
tCtx.drawImage(img,1,1, 98, 98);
};

img.src = 'http://imgur.com/GvRewu7.png';

tCtx.clip();

var cSi = tCan.toDataURL();
```

---

#### Simple way of cropping an image via an oval

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/mdofqjx2/1/

You can create a path and then draw a circle. If you want to draw an oval just modify the scale `ctx.scale`

```
var c = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var img = new Image();
img.src = "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000532546226/dbe5f0727b69487016ffd67a6689e75a.jpeg";

img.onload = function()
{
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);

    ctx.save();
    ctx.scale(2,1);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(150, 150, 150, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.clip();
    ctx.scale(0.5,1);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    ctx.restore(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I used the "Simple way" and managed to insert my bezier curves in place of drawing an arc (coursework restrictions), and it still works. Looking over the fixed version, I need to do this repeatedly so adding new cavases (canvasi?) isn't really an option.

Comment: What you can do is just create two canvases on your page at start up and just reference those two instead, I have updated my answer

Comment: Nice answer(s) -- upvote. Since the OP commented that they need to do this repeatedly, you might also show drawing into an oval using compositing. Compositing is done on the GPU so you get the performance advantage of hardware acceleration.